# Sum of Items field in collection of collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to see if it's possible, but I would like to get the sum of a field in an item in a collection of collections.

I have the following in my controller:

```
    $prefiltered_contacts = Contact::with(['donations' => function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereMonth('date_received', $request->month)
                ->whereYear('date_received', $request->year);
    }])->get();

    $contacts = $prefiltered_contacts ->filter(function ($contact) {
        return $contact->donations->isNotEmpty();
    });
```

My donation class has the following:

```
public function monetary_donations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Payments_Distribution', 'donation_id','id');
}
```

Now the last part of this is that in the `Payments_Distribution` class, there is a field titled `amount`.

If I was coming directly from the Donation model, I would access the sum of the monetary donations as `$donation->monetary_donations->sum('amount');` and I would receive the sum. But how would I go about doing this from the Contact model? Or is that even possible given that it would need to go through a collection of donations to get to the collection of monetary_donations? I'm trying to get a report of all Contacts donations (and monetary donations) and output a subtotal of the monetary_donations for that specific period.

Answer (score 1):

[Sum](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sum) accepts a closure as the argument. So you could do something like this:

```
$sum = $donations->sum(function ($donation) {
    return $donation->monetary_donations->sum('amount');
});
```

Or 1 level higher (from `$contacts`):

```
$sum = $contacts->sum(function ($contact) {
    return $contact->donations->sum(function ($donation) {
        return $donation->monetary_donations->sum('amount');
    });
});
```

Edit:

I would also recommend eager loading your relationships and filtering out contacts without donations with SQL rather than collections:

```
$contacts = Contact::with(['donations' => function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query
            ->with('monetary_donations')
            ->whereMonth('date_received', $request->month)
            ->whereYear('date_received', $request->year);
}])
    ->whereHas('donations') // Filter out those without donations with SQL
    ->get();
```